# Custom animation on up navigation

Tags: android, animation

When I instanciate a new Activity is use a custom animation like this:

```
Intent registerIntent = new Intent();
registerIntent.setClassName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".activity.RegisterActivity");
startActivity(registerIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

This way the current/old activity slides out to the left, while the new activity slides in from the right.

When in the new RegisterActivity I use following code to handle the animation when the user uses the "Back" button:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Now the current activity leaves to the right and the old activity (from before) comes back in from the left.

I also tried to handle the "Up" Navigation like this, but with no result:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

How would i use a custom animation on "Up" navigation? Any suggestions on how to better use animations?

EDIT:
slide_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Comment: Maybe there is another way to solve my problem: Can I change the behaviour of the "Up/Home" Button so that it does the same as if I would press "Back"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following: Now it works:

Old:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)));
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

New:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)));
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood... I think that this resolve.

```
Intent registerIntent = new Intent();
registerIntent.setClassName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".activity.RegisterActivity");
   startActivity(registerIntent);
   overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.animation_in+right_to_left,
            R.anim.animation_out_right_to_left);

public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_in_left_to_right,
                R.anim.animation_out_left_to_right);
 }
```

animation_in_left_to_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:duration="500"/>

</set>
```

animation_out_left_to_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="200%"
         android:duration="500"/>
 </set>
```

animation_in_right_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate android:fromXDelta="200%" android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

animation_out_right_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
 android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%"
 android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

you use the same logic to UP navigation

Comment: I dont know why this would change my current behaviour. I already provided a custom navigation on the "Up" case. This does not get recognized at all. So there is some error in the Code and not in the definition of the animation itself.
I added my transition xmls in the post.